# How to add new page to a Draw.IO document

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I would like to have a single document that contains several diagrams (all the UML diagrams that I need for my project).

How can I add a new page in a Draw.IO document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the diagrams.net interface there is a plus "+" symbol that allows you to add a new page:

[image: The diagrams.net editor interface with the bottom pages bar highlighted]

If you're using the draw.io whiteboard theme, you have to enable pages via the preference menu first:

[image: The preferences menu of draw.io expanded with the enabled/disable pages menu option highlighted]

Once enabled the pages option appears bottom-right of the interface as three vertical dots:

[image: The pages menu enabled at the bottom-right of the draw.io whiteboard interface]

Clicking that brings up the pages actions and details. One of the actions is "insert page":

[image: The expanded pages menu in the draw.io whiteboard interface. It shows the available pages and actions, including add new page]

Comment: ok. Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 3):

You can add more pages to a draw.io file by placing an object where the new page belongs. The new page will automatically added in order to contain the new object. If you want to have a new page on the right of the current page, place the new object on the right the current page. If you want the new page below the current page, place the new object below the current page.

For more information, check the link below
https://support.draw.io/questions/2949188/how-to-add-pages-to-a-diagram

Comment: This does not actually add a "separate" diagram. It just makes the diagram larger.

Answer (score 1):

Even though draw.io doesn't support multiple pages, there is a workaround which kind of solves this: *Layers* (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd>).

You can add several layers to a document using the *Layers* panel, and then tick the layer(s) you want to see, and select the layer you want to add new stuff to and work with. If you have created stuff at one layer you want to move, simply select the elements, and then select the new layer and hit the button to move selected items to current layer.

Usually layers are used for purposes like different detail levels, or adding explanations/comments on a separate layer. Or in a floor plan you could have the base layer showing the rooms, and then extra layers for electricitiy, pipes, furniture, ... In this context you'll show several layers at the same time.

However, opting to only display one level at a time, you'll mimic having pages and the contents can be totally separated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Draw.IO Version 13.6.2 (or even earlier) has the option to add new pages (in the lower bar, called "insert page").

Then you can work on *different pages*, in the *same document*.

And finnaly you can iterate through the pages with "Ctrl-Shift-Page-Up" and "Ctrl-Shift-Page-Down", which I find very handy!